# malloc: *** error for object: pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: c++, malloc, new-operator, delete-operator

I keep getting this error when I run my code. I'm not sure why I keep getting this error because I call `delete` on two objects which I have allocated using the `new` operator.

I have tried running it in Xcode and I get a `thread 1: signal SIGABRT error`.

**PokerV2.cpp**

```cpp
int main() {    
    bool game_flag = true;

    Poker_Game game1;

    game1.initialise_game();

    game1.game_run();

    while (game_flag) { 
        char input = 'a';
        game_flag = false;
        game1.game_run(game1.get_current_players());
        std::cout << "Press 'y' to continue";
        std::cin >> input;
        if (input == 'y') {
            game_flag = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**poker_game_class.hpp**

```cpp
void Poker_Game::game_run() {
    int lowest = 10;
    int num = 0;
    // Create the deck and table dynamically
    Deck *deck = new Deck();
    Table *table = new Table(_player_num);

    deck->deal_cards(table->get_all_players(), _player_num, *table);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        table->set_game_flag(i);
        table->set_highest_bet(0);

        for (int z = 0; z < table->get_player_num(); z++) {
            table->players_turn(z);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < table->get_player_num(); i++) {
        if (table->get_player(i).calculate_score(*table) < lowest) {
            num = i;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "The winner is player: " << num << "\n";
    std::cout << "The winner has won: £" << table->get_pot() << "\n";

    //Add total pot to players cash

    float current_balance = table->get_player(num).get_balance();
    float balance_after_win = current_balance + table->get_pot();

    table->get_player(num).set_balance(balance_after_win);

    std::cout << "Winners balance: £" << table->get_player(num).get_balance();

    this->Current_players = table->get_all_players();

    delete deck;
    delete table;
}
```

The error occurs in the `game_run` function just when the `deck` and `table` are deleted.

[The output from the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TO9FO.png)

Below is the linked GitHub repository

https://github.com/mbh1620/PokerV2/tree/master/PokerV2

Comment: Minimal, working example would be more helpful.

Comment: You're either freeing the same pointer twice, or you're trying to free memory that was never instantiated (which is what the error message is saying!).

Without a code line, nobody can help you. You're currently talking to a mechanic, saying the car's making a noise and then buggering off home.

Comment: The error occurs at the delete deck;. However I instantiated deck at the top of the function. Also this error does not come up every single time which is odd.

Comment: In this particular code there seems to be no need to allocate these objects on the heap at all.

Comment: Another possibility is that you've corrupted memory.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin If `delete deck` doesn't work after `deck = new Deck()`, then allocating the object on the stack isn't going to fix whatever's actually wrong.

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: @jamesdlin Which is why removing unrelated dynamic allocation is an excellent way of zeroing in the actual problem.

Comment: In the main loop you pass a function call into the 'game1.run()' call . . . I'm just wondering what that is really doing as the method does not accept any parameters.

Comment: It looks like the overloaded version of game.run does not delete the table or deck . . . I'd poke through the logic with a debugger to see what is happening, but to me it looks like you have a memory leak.

Comment: The first game.run() initiates the right amount of players and then once that run has completed the players are put into a temporary array. This temporary array is then passed into the next game.run() which is in the loop. I have done this so that in between each hand of poker the players will keep the right amount of money which they won in the previous hand. I have copied most of the code into the overloaded version so it deletes table and deck.

Comment: You have not provided the code with the error. Yes the error manifests when you call delete bu that is not where the error actually occurred. The error occured where you overwrote some memory that is not yours (probably). So it is probably in the `Deck` or `Table` class which is not provided. So it is impossible to debug.

Comment: Once you get this running and working. Please take the code to https://codereview.stackexchange.com to get a run down of ways you can improve.

Comment: I recommend running your code through something like [valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a problem here:

```
Player * Table::get_all_players()
{
    return Players;
}
```

You are returning a pointer (and ownership) to `Poker_Game` when it calls this function:

```
    // One place you call it from.
    set_current_players(table -> get_all_players());
```

The problem is that two objects are now claiming ownership of the `Players` and both call `delete []` on the pointer they have.

```
Poker_Game::~Poker_Game()
{
    delete[] Current_players;
}
Table::~Table()
{
    delete[] Players;
}
```

Not saying this is your only error.

You have basically fallen in to the trap of bad ownership semantics within your application. In C++ we resolved this problem (unlike C) by using specific type and language constructs to explicitly mark ownership. This way we explicitly know who owns an object and thus who is responsible for deleting them.

Your problems can easily be solved by doing a couple of things.

1. Don't dynamically allocate arrays.
   Use `std::vector<>` to manage the allocation for you.
2. Don't dynamically allocate objects whose lifespan does not live longer than the function.
   Simply use a local variable and let the scope rules handle it.
3. If you must dynamically allocate an object use a smart pointer.
   std::unique_ptr and std::shared_ptr manage the memory for allocated objects very well.
4. If you pass an object to another object (and are not passing ownership) then pass by reference (rather than pointer).
   This tells the other class they don't own the object and thus should not delete it.

A simple rule to live by is "Separation of Concerns".

A class should either be business logic or it should be resource management. So your class should either handle the logic of poker or they should handle the logic of managing the memory you allocate (not both). So any class that is handling a poker thing should not call new/delete a class that handles new/delete should not have poker logic in it.

Now the standard libraries provide a lot of resource management code so you don't need to, you can simply use the existing code and concentrate on your poker logic. If after the game is working you decide the standard resource management is not efficient enough you can concentrate on upgrading that as a separate task.